# How do I detect whether a SharePoint calendar item has been changed in Outlook or via the browser?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have a SharePoint calendar which users can connect to and view/edit in Outlook. I want to be able to create a workflow that is fired when an item is changed or updated and then use an If statement to determine whether the change was made in Outlook or via the user's browser. Is this even possible? I cannot use a code based solution (much as I would like to) as I do not have access to use one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having scoured the net, it would appear not. The only way that I have used before, but it is clunky, is to create a field that can only be edited in SharePoint and an identical table that holds the previous version. The workflow can detect if the SharePoint only field has changed in relation to previous value held in the other table, and use this to direct to SharePoint only or Outlook only code as required.